# fading out fixed navigation bar whe scrolling down, fading in when back on top of the page

Tags: jquery

I have a fixed navigation at the top of the browser window and I want it to fade out when I scroll down and fade in when I scroll back to the top.

```
$(function(){

var didScroll = false;
var topbar = $('.topbar');
var $window = $(window);

function fadeOutScroll(){
    if(didScroll){
        if($window.scrollTop()>40){
            topbar.animate({'opacity':'0.4'},'slow');   
        }else{ 
            topbar.animate({'opacity':'1'},'100');  
        }           
        didScroll = false;
    }       
}

$window.scroll(function(){
    didScroll = true;
});

window.setInterval(fadeOutScroll,50);

});
```

It fades out when I scroll down, but when I go back to the top it doesn't fade in every time. It acts weird.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I hope it works not tested though

```
$(function(){

var didScroll = false;
var scrollUp = false;
var topbar = $('.topbar');
var $window = $(window);

function fadeOutScroll(){
    if(didScroll){
        topbar.animate({'opacity':(scrollUp?'1':'0.4')},'100');  
        didScroll = false;
    }       
}

$window.scroll(function(){
    didScroll = true;
    scrollUp = ($window.scrollTop() < 40);
});

window.setInterval(fadeOutScroll,50);

});
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. Unfortunatelly this doesn't solve the problem, it seems to act the same way.   
You can take a look [here](http://jsbin.com/ezaxuf).

Comment: It works only sometimes. I'd like to achieve same behavior as it's in gmail when you scroll down while reading email, the top bar gets a little box shadow and it works immediately. My solution doesn't.